# ¿Como identificar un arroba en un input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, aplicación-web, react-hooks

Estoy tratando de hacer un autocomplete con React, tengo mi lista de elementos para completar pero cuando ejecuto el onChange para identificar si el usuario ha escrito la @ no me la muestra

```
const changeAutocomplete = (e)=> {
    const arrEmails = ["gmail.com", "hotmail.com", "yahoo.com", "live.com", "outlook.com", "msn.com", "google.com"];
    if(e.target.value === "@"){
      console.log(arrEmails);
    }
  }
```

Si comparo una letra si me muestra el console con el array

```
const changeAutocomplete = (e)=> {
    const arrEmails = ["gmail.com", "hotmail.com", "yahoo.com", "live.com", "outlook.com", "msn.com", "google.com"];
    if(e.target.value === "a"){
      console.log(arrEmails);
    }
  }
```

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Creo que es por que estás comparando el valor completo, si lo que pones en el input es `paco@` el valor de `e.target.value` será `paco@`, por tanto podrías usar:

```
   if(e.target.value.endsWith("@")){
     console.log(arrEmails);
   }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!